# Убрать пробел в параметрах ссылки

Tags: href, html

```
<a <? if($_GET['act'] == 'sort' && $_GET['cat'] == 1) echo 'class="active"'; ?> href="#">test</a>
```

Если нет class="active", то вид не очень красивый:

```
<a  href="#">test</a>
```

"a" и двойной пробел. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы оставался 1 пробел?

```
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Comment: @ModaL, какая разница Вам, как будет выглядеть Ваш исходный код? Не нравится такое представление - каноникализируйте. Все такие вещи [каноникализация](www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) уберёт.

Comment: Мяу! Это что? Чистописание html кода?!

Comment: @danpetruk, не только html ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хах, ну и вопросы у вас! Это что из академии изобразительного искусства имени web 3.0 чтоли?

```
<a<? if($_GET['act'] == 'sort' && $_GET['cat'] == 1) echo ' class="active"'; ?> href="#">test</a>
```

наслаждайтесь.

Comment: @slipshod, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам рюшечки или ехать? не нравится такой код -- используйте шаблоны для вывода, вообще так использовать пхп внутри html вообще не айс.

Comment: +1. Сказано всё по делу. Php тут неф|/|га не нужен

Answer (score 0):

```
<a <?=($_GET['act']=='sort' && $_GET['cat']==1)?'class="active"':''?>href="#">test</a>
```

Comment: @злобный, не помогло :( Да и вид кода ужасный. Как-нибудь иначе можно?

Comment: @ModaL, а чем же использования тернарного оператора так "ужасно"? ))

Comment: Если в 5 ссылках так поставить, то в двух будет нормально, а в остальных трёх всё равно пробелы...

Comment: ну еще бы работало, тернарный оператор выдает либо значение1, либо значение2, в вашем случае используйте либо if/elseif либо switch/case

Comment: @ModaL как раз хороший код, а то, что в 2х работае, а в других не работает -- ищите где косяк или приводите примеры. этот код везде выдаст один и тот же результат.